# How do you know if all means completely or the whole quantity?

Tags: meaning

> The shoes are all black.

Does this mean the shoes are completely black or all of the shoes are black?

> The men are all happy.

Does it mean all of the men are happy or the men are completely happy?

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a way of determining this without context?

Comment: There are alternative ways to rewrite this to be less ambiguous ("Every shoe is black", "The shoes are black all over", etc), but without looking at the shoes or otherwise considering the context, you can't know.

Comment: One way of relieving the ambiguity is to use a hyphen to create a compound adjective: "They are all black shoes"/"They are all-black shoes" but that doesn't really work as a subject complement. However, "all happy" does only have one meaning because "all happy" meaning "completely happy" is wholly unidiomatic.